What is the relation between Shor's code and the GHZ states?
The logical states for Shor's code $|0_L\rangle$ and $|1_L\rangle$  are
$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        |0_L\rangle = \left(\frac{|000\rangle+|111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\otimes{}3}\\
        |1_L\rangle = \left(\frac{|000\rangle-|111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\otimes{}3}\\   
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
From what I can tell, these are exactly the GHZ states (for $|1_L\rangle$ apply $Z$ gate):
$$
\begin{equation}
    |0_L\rangle = \left(|GHZ\rangle\right)^{\otimes{}3}\\
    |1_L\rangle = \left(Z_1|GHZ\rangle\right)^{\otimes{}3}\\   
\end{equation}
$$
Am I correct saying that each triplet of qubits in Shor's code is a GHZ state ($|GHZ\rangle$)?
Furthermore, in this paper they use the GHZ states for logical $|+_L\rangle$ and $|-_L\rangle$. Is this just a relabelling? The circuits shown in Figure 1 are identical to the conventional GHZ preparation ones. If so, what would be the reason to do this?
